# Queues at Madame Tussauds London with a timed ticket

Tags: uk, london, tourist-traps

Madame Tussauds London offers ["timed" tickets](https://support.madametussauds.co.uk/hc/en-us/articles/212664005-How-does-the-time-slot-system-work-and-what-time-should-I-turn-up-) for a specific 15 minute arrival window.

However, I've read some online resources, e.g. [this one](http://www.topdogdays.com/insiders-guides/insiders-guide-to-madame-tussauds-london/), saying that you still might have to queue for a while even with one of these tickets. Is this true, and if so, how do the queues compare to the "normal" walk-up queues?

Comment: It's so variable, especially now with the school breaks. Honestly, the only way to be absolutely sure about your queuing time at Mme Tussauds is to get the priority tickets (erstwhile Marylebone resident).

Comment: `queue for a while even with one of these tickets`  Yes you might have to. They do have a separate queue for pre-booked tickets but if the visitors number are large you will have to queue. Saying from experience. I queued for maybe 20 minutes to collect my tickets in May.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMO this question is either "Does Madame Tussauds London publish waiting times" or too broad. It seems they do not publish (though OP may wish to call +44 (0) 871 282 9200 to check whether such statistics are collected even if not shown on their website).

Other evidence (in line with @Gayot Fow's Comment) is that delays are variable, for example as mentioned on [Trip Advisor](https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/ShowTopic-g186338-i17-k5333254-Queues_for_Madame_Tussauds-London_England.html).

In view of "Two for One" tickets  at least the time of day makes a big difference. Even pre-booking may not help:

> .went at 10 a.m. on a weekday............went right in.........the only lineup was for people who had prebooked tickets

though admittedly from four years ago.

Factors that I would expect to make a difference include train strikes, school holidays, weather, exchange rates ... and almost anything else imaginable.

> Is this true

Yes.

> how do the queues compare to the "normal" walk-up queues?

It depends. They may be shorter or longer, even perhaps about the same.